# Can i use ip address as Object array key?

Tags: php, json, for-loop

I m having json file as

> {"103.186.190.216":1398640126}

i read the file and json decode it returs as

> stdClass Object ( [203.196.190.226] => 1398640126 )

How can i print simple as

```
echo $json_arr->203.196.190.226;
```

1. Can have ip as key ?

i know can retrieve it by

```
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $val) {
        echo $val;
    }
```

Or how can print it in for loop rather than foreach

And also how can push values inside these type of object array

Coz normal php `array_push();` Didn't work.

Or on the lighter note what is best way to create these type of array which we want give the key And value dynamically ?

Comment: @PleaseStand can you also tell how to push in this type of array before clossing or watever

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax:

```
echo $json_arr->{'203.196.190.226'};
```

Comment: Does anyone know the exact name of this syntax? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: how can we push key & value in these array

Comment: @SathyaRaj Do you mean setting a value? Try `$json_arr{'203.196.190.226'} = ...`.

Comment: @SathyaRaj What did not work? Please provide more information. Check out this example: https://eval.in/137934